# cant pause mediaplayer after reopen activity

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

Here in my `MainActivity.java` I have an object `MediaPlayer`, which plays a sound when you click `playB` button and pause by pressing `pauseB`. Everything is working fine. But if you re-open the app and click `pauseB`, the sound continues to play. How to fix it? How to catch the current playing `MediaPlayer`?

```
    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    Button playB;
    Button pauseB;
    Context c;
    MediaPlayer mp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Button playB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playB);
        Button pauseB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pauseB);


            mp = mp.create(this, R.raw.fawaid_1);
        playB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mp.start();
            }
        });
        pauseB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mp.pause();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you re-open the app, `onCreate` is called again, hence you have a new `MediaPlayer` object, and from that moment, play and pause buttons will control that new player object instead of a previous one. That's why your pause button will have no effect on the sound that started BEFORE you minimized the app. And if you press play button now, you will have two sounds playing at the same time

one way to overcome this, is to check if media player has already been initialized:

```
if(mp==null)
mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.fawaid_1);
```

Comment: the problem is that I declare the object `MediaPlayer` here : `public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
Button playB;
Button pauseB;
Context c;
MediaPlayer mp;` it has already created and has the status `!=null`. Isn't it?

Comment: @JoeSilent you declare a variable and then you create an object by calling `MediaPlayer.create()` method. until you call that method, `mp` will be `null`

Answer (score 0):

It is advisable to use Service with AIDL in developing music player.
Reasons.

1. You can retain the control again once you go back in your activity.
2. It is easy to perform an inter process communication.

Here is a simple music Player that runs on the Background, [Music Player](https://github.com/Ecobin/MusicPlayerTutorial)

> *The song I used in this music player is Owned by SnowFlakes*